# I'm not able to solve the following indefinite integral

Tags: calculus

I have to solve the indefinite integral:

$$\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x(x-9)(x-5)}}dx$$

Comment: Is that really the integral you want? (The antiderivative is not an elementary function.)

Comment: $$(x-9)(x-5)=(x-7)^2-2^2$$ So, start with $$x-7=2\sec\theta$$  then $$\tan\dfrac{\theta}2=t$$

Comment: They are so-called [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Comment: Yes! Exactly that!

Comment: Ok thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

According to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+1%2Fsqrt%28%28x%28x-9%29%28x-5%29%29%29+dx):
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x(x-9)(x-5)}} dx = \frac{i\sqrt{\frac{4}{x-9} + 1}(x-9)^{1.5}\sqrt{\frac{x}{x-9}}F\left(i \sinh^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{x-9}},\frac{9}{4}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{(x-9)(x-5)x}} + C$$
Where $F(x,m)$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind, with parameter $m=k^2$
Wolfram alpha does not give a list of steps for this problem.

As [Frank Science](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23875/frank-science) commented, this seems to be an [elliptic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) which is any integral defined as such:
$$f(x)=\int_c^x R\left(t, \sqrt{P(t)}\right) dt$$
where $R$ is a [rational function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) and $P$ is a polynomial of degree 3 or 4

In this case
$$R(a,b)=\frac{1}{b}$$
and
$$P(t)=t(t-9)(t-5)$$